# Why is my Finder Blue now instead of the dark gray?

Tags: mac, finder, color

My Mac finder color is now dark blue/purple instead of the new gray nightmode color. I'm on the latest update of Mojave.

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue and it only arises when I use secondary desktops. When I move everything over to my primary desktop the Finder colour goes back to normal. When closing and reopening those secondary desktops the issue returns. Only restarts seem to get rid of the issue which is frustrating. It seems like a bug to me, but I am still looking for a solution to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably because the Finder has some transparency to it. It'll blend in the gray color with whatever is under it, so you probably have a background (or something else) under the Finder window with that blue/purple color

macOS Big Sur (11.0) adds an option to toggle this setting in System Preferences > Allow wallpaper tinting in windows, so you can turn it off now if you want to (provided you update, of course)

Here’s the control to change the color of Finder’s tabs:

[image]

Comment: Any clue how to turn it off?

Comment: @driverpizza You can use the Graphite accent color, which will also make the window stoplight buttons gray.

Comment: I have the same effect with nothing behind the finder so I believe this answer is incorrect

Comment: Something is always behind/underneath the Finder. Whether it's a website, your desktop background, a program, etc., it's just the window/program/picture underneath. :)

Comment: The issue happens even without people who have transparency enabled in Finder, like myself, and other commenters here.

Comment: @Nathan, you can't enable or disable it. It's built into the OS. The color of the Finder will always be a mixture of "summed" colors underneath it, mixed with white or gray, depending on if you're using a dark or light mode.
It's a design choice by Apple

Comment: @David Oh okay.  But I still agree with Psi's comment on the question:  It happens to me only when dealing with a secondary desktop (and seems perhaps a desktop that was on a secondary monitor before I unplugged).  Also, restarting (and letting all the same windows reappear after restarting) solves the problem, whereas moving the bluish Finder around does not solve the problem.  So the answer is definitely not just "I didn't notice the Finder was on top of something bluish."